# Not able to see who is calling in HTC Desire C when connected to computer

Tags: htc-desire, caller-id

When **HTC desire C** is connected to the laptop, the screen gets locked and if a call comes, the phone is not showing the caller details. Also there is no option to unlock the phone when it is connected to the computer.

Only options I left with are

1. To answer the call unknowingly who is calling
2. To wait till it becomes a missed call.

Any ideas to see the who is calling when It is connected to the laptop.

I tried the `Stay Awake while charging` option and set it to `On`; but no use.